# How to reference an object that hasn't yet been instantiated

Tags: c#, instantiation

I'm trying to model a flow chart in C#. I'll simplify the classes a bit, but the basic idea is that a given `Step` points to another `Step`. What I want to do is set up the linkage between everything in one place in code. For example, I want `step1` to point to `step2` which points to `step3`

```
class Step
{
   Step nextStep;

   // Constructor
   public Step(Step nextStep) { this.nextStep = nextStep; }
}

class Chart
{
    private readonly Step step1;
    private readonly Step step2;
    private readonly Step step3;

    public Chart()
    {
        step1 = new Step(step2);
        step2 = new Step(step3);
        step3 = new Step(null);
    }
}

static void main()
{
   Chart myChart = new Chart();
}
```

This compiles fine, but if the nextStep object hasn't been instantiated yet, the reference is lost upon instantiation.

In this example, `step1`'s constructor is passed `step2`, which is `null` at that point. I was hoping that when `step2` is instantiated, the reference within `step1` would properly point to the newly created `step2`, but it doesn't.

It's looking like I need to first instantiate ALL the objects, then go back and set the links via a setter or some such. Is that the proper way? Or can it be done in the constructor as I tried?

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles as you are using an uninitialized variable (step2) when instantiating step1

Comment: It didn't compile for me...

------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
D:\Projects\Test\Console\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs(22,30): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'step2'
D:\Projects\Test\Console\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs(23,30): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'step3'

Comment: @Mick - Apologies. I tried to boil it down to simplify, but it's slightly different. I'll modify my code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to work backward: `step3` first, then `step2` that addresses `step3` in its constructor, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an actual object which doesn't point to anything else.

```
step3 = new Step(null);
```

From there, set your steps in reverse order, until you reach the first step.

```
step2 = new Step(step3);
step1 = new Step(step2);
```

Comment: I'll fix that since it might be confusing, but the issue is with step1 and step2. They will always have nextStep set to null.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in the constructor, the object will have to be created first. One way of using dependency injection would be to pass in the parent and assign the new step to be the parent's next step.

Example:

```
class Step
{
    private Step nextStep;

    public Step() {}

    public Step(Step parent)
    {
        parent.nextStep = this;
    }
}

static void main()
{
    Step step1, step2, step3;

    step1 = new Step();
    step2 = new Step(step1);
    step3 = new Step(step2);
}
```